# trying to use recursion to find the possibilities of two known numbers adding to N

Tags: java, recursion

I have this recursion problem that I spent hours on but unable to transform some of my thoughts into code. I have a problem where I need to build a function that tries to fit 3's and 1's into a given number(n). I try to get n from user but then I cannot go further. Basically I need to calculate the possibility of 3's and 1's that add up to n. I know that a constant solution is that I can fit 1n times into n.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input number: ");
    int n = ask.nextInt(); 

}

public static int getPossibility(int n, int k, int p) {

    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n / p == n ) {
        return n;
    } else {
        int ctr = n;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

            ctr += getPossibility(n, k - 1, p - 1) ;
        }
   return ctr;
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood what you meant. With this code you try to figure out how many combinatios start by 1 and how many start by 3. Then you just need to sum up and you'll get your solution.

```
public int possibilities (int n){
    int pos1=0;
    int pos3 =0;
    if (n>2){
        pos3 = possibilities(n-3);
    }
    if (n>0) {
        pos1 = possibilities(n-1);
    }
    return pos1 + pos3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i mean. My english is not the best so i think that had to do with me not being understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but if you want to calculate how many times 3s and 1s fit into a number you can do it like this:

```
int threes = n / 3;
int ones = n % threes * 3;
```